# Error when connecting geth to local network rpc

Tags: go-ethereum, javascript, nodes

I have been working on trying to run a geth node on my home server (FreeBSD jail on a freenas) and setting up my laptop geth to attach to the rpc to save space on my laptop. I have confirmed that the geth node on the server works and I can connect locally on the jail through `geth attach http://localhost:8545`. However, when I try to connect to the node through my windows laptop using `geth.exe attach http://XXX:8545` I get the error:

`Fatal: Failed to start the JavaScript console: api modules: invalid character 'i' looking for beginning of value`.

Has anyone tried something similar or know why this may be happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `geth 1.8`, if you're using a name instead of IP to attach to, you need to set the `rpcvhosts` option when starting `geth`:

`geth --testnet console --light --rpc --rpcport 33000 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcaddr "127.0.0.1" --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal" --rpcvhosts=yourDomainHere.com`

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. I was using the jail hostname to connect through the local network. Thanks!